# Python script using Minneapolis / St. Paul Metro Transit's API to tell you how long till next bus

Tags: python, beginner, json, api

I have written a program which will tell you how long it is until the next bus on “BUS ROUTE” leaving from “BUS STOP NAME” going “DIRECTION” using the api defined at http://svc.metrotransit.org/.

Example:

```
$ metro.py "metro blue line" "target field station platform 1" "south" 
6 minutes
```

I am very new to Python and wondering how this code could be better — more efficient, follow best practices, etc. What would you do differently?

```
import requests, sys, time

# need to have each: route, stop & direction
if len(sys.argv) != 4:
    sys.exit("Please be sure to enter a route, stop, and direction.")

route = sys.argv[1]
stop = sys.argv[2]
direction = sys.argv[3]

url = "http://svc.metrotransit.org/NexTrip/"

def getData (uri, key, value, arg):
    resp = requests.get(url + uri + "?format=json")
    data = resp.json()

    # default in case of invalid input 
    dataID = -1

    while True: 
        try: sys.exit(uri + str(resp.status_code))

        except:
            for item in data:
                if item[key].lower().find(arg) > -1:
                    dataID = item[value]
                    break
            return dataID

routeID = getData("Routes", "Description", "Route", route)

if routeID < 0:
    sys.exit(route + " is not a valid route.")

uri = routeID
directionID =  getData("Directions/" + uri, "Text", "Value", direction)

if directionID < 0:
    sys.exit(route + " does not go " + direction + ".")

uri += "/" + directionID 
stopID = getData("Stops/" + uri, "Text", "Value", stop)

if stopID < 0:
    sys.exit(stop + " is not along " + route + " going " + direction + ".")

uri += "/" + stopID
timeID = getData(uri, "RouteDirection", "DepartureTime", direction)

if timeID != -1:
    #Get 10 digit timestamp from response, - from current time, and / by 60 to get minutes as an integer
    time = int((float(timeID[6:16]) - time.time()) // 60)
    if time > 1:
        print str(time) + " minutes"
    else:
        print "1 minute or less"
```

Answer (score 4):

[As Ludisposed said in his answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/177669/98493), yours is a very top-down approach. The minimum you should do is put this into a function, so you can re-use it. Here I rewrote your code quite significantly. Instead of returning `-1`, use the fact that a Python function returns `None` by default, which is a better safe value than `-1`.

I also completely re-wrote your `getData` function. Honestly, I have no idea what half of that was trying to do. All you need to do is iterate over the `data`. No need for a `try: sys.exit(...) except:` (which will always call what is inside the `except`, so why bother?). Also no need for a `while True` loop, if you are only ever going to go through it once.

I added the simple `argparse` parser and added the calling code under a [`if __name__ == "__main__":`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do) guard.

```
import argparse
import time
import sys
import requests

URL = "http://svc.metrotransit.org/NexTrip/{}?format=json"


def get(path, key, value, arg):
    resp = requests.get(URL.format(path))
    data = resp.json()
    for item in data:
        if arg in item[key].lower():
            return item[value]


def next_bus(route, stop, direction):
    route_id = get("Routes", "Description", "Route", route)
    if route_id is None:
        raise RuntimeError("{} is not a valid route.".format(route))

    direction_id = get("Directions/{}".format(route_id),
                           "Text", "Value", direction)
    if direction_id is None:
        raise RuntimeError("{} does not go {}.".format(route, direction))

    stop_id = get("Stops/{}/{}".format(route_id, direction_id), "Text", "Value", stop)
    if stop_id is None:
        raise RuntimeError("{} is not along {} going {}.".format(
            stop, route, direction))

    time_ = get("{}/{}/{}".format(route_id, direction_id, stop_id),
                    "RouteDirection", "DepartureTime", direction)
    if time_ is None:
        raise RuntimeError("Could not get next connection.")
    return int((float(time_[6:16]) - time.time()) // 60)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("route")
    parser.add_argument("stop")
    parser.add_argument("direction")
    args = parser.parse_args()
    time = next_bus(**vars(args))
    if time > 1:
        print "{} minutes".format(time)
    else:
        print "1 minute or less"
```

---

Alternatively, you could make this a `class` and use `property` for the different ids. This would allow you to have an object like `trip_home = Connection(route, direction, stop)`, on which you could call `trip_home.next` to get the latest connection.

The different ids are looked up upon the initialization of the class. Calls to `trip_home.next` will only need to get the next connection. This assumes that the ids do not change during the runtime of the program, of course.

```
import argparse
import time
import sys
import requests


class Connection:
    url = "http://svc.metrotransit.org/NexTrip/{}?format=json"

    def __init__(self, route, stop, direction):
        self.route = route
        self.stop = stop
        self.direction = direction
        self.route_id = self.get_route_id()
        self.direction_id = self.get_direction_id()
        self.stop_id = self.get_stop_id()

    def __str__(self):
        return "{self.route} from {self.stop} due {self.direction}. Next connection in {self.next} minutes.".format(self=self)

    def get(self, path, key, value, arg):
        resp = requests.get(self.url.format(path))
        data = resp.json()
        for item in data:
            if arg in item[key].lower():
                return item[value]

    def get_route_id(self):
        id_ = self.get("Routes", "Description", "Route", self.route)
        if id_ is None:
            raise RuntimeError(
                "{self.route} is not a valid route.".format(self=self))
        return id_

    def get_direction_id(self):
        id_ = self.get(
            "Directions/{self.route_id}".format(self=self), "Text", "Value", self.direction)
        if id_ is None:
            raise RuntimeError("{self.route} does not go {self.direction}.".format(
                self=self))
        return id_

    def get_stop_id(self):
        id_ = self.get(
            "Stops/{self.route_id}/{self.direction_id}".format(self=self), "Text", "Value", self.stop)
        if id_ is None:
            raise RuntimeError(
                "{self.stop} is not along {self.route} going {self.direction}.".format(self=self))
        return id_

    @property
    def next(self):
        time_ = self.get("{self.route_id}/{self.direction_id}/{self.stop_id}".format(self=self),
                         "RouteDirection", "DepartureTime", self.direction)
        if time_ is None:
            raise RuntimeError(
                "Could not find next connection on route {self.route} from {self.stop} due {self.direction}".format(self=self))
        return int((float(time_[6:16]) - time.time()) // 60)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("route")
    parser.add_argument("stop")
    parser.add_argument("direction")
    args = parser.parse_args()
    trip_home = Connection(args.route, args.stop, args.direction)
    print trip_home
```

Comment: Why not change the `print` statement to a function for Python 3 compatibility?

Comment: @Coal_ Because the OP used Python 2 `print`. But you are right, in this case there would be no difference when using it as if it was alreayd Python 3.

Comment: @Graipher thanks so much, this is very informative and makes a lot of sense!

Answer (score 1):

## PEP8 and Readability

When coding it is nice to uphold a standard, it makes your code more readable for others and yourself. In python we have [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). Your code has a few **PEP8** violations and other readability issues.

- Multiple imports on one line, imports should each have thier own line.
- Use a `if __name__ == '__main__':` block
- globals should be uppercase `URL = 'http://my_url.com'`
- Use [argparse](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/argparse.html) over `sys.argv`, much easier to handle arguments that way
- Functions and variables should be `snake_case` instead of `pascalCase`
- Use `string.format()` instead of string concatinations

## Other

- Your code has a Top-Down structure, I would refractor this into
  smaller pieces.
- `sys.exit(0)` would be better (which means the program closed normally), and then `print '{0} is not a valid route'.format(route)`